# Call Partial View on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 drop down lists in a Partial View and want to display 1st drop down on 1st `Search` click and 2nd drop down on 2nd `Search` click in View. The `Index` contains list of 2 Students Name and each student has `Search` button.Please guide me how to write code to display drop down based on button click condition. Any help and guidance is highly appreciated.

My `Index` View:

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentProject.StudentDetail>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
        </th>    
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />

            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentId }) 

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div id="searchResults">

</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = '@Url.Action("DisplaySearchResults", "Student")';
    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#searchResults').load(url);
    })

</script>
```

My Partial View `_StudentLocation`:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    Locations Details
</head>
<body>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option>Auckland</option>
        <option>Wellington</option>
    </select>

    <select class="dropdown">
        <option>Hamilton</option>
        <option>Christchurch</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

My Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace StudentProject.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private StudentEntities db = new StudentEntities();

        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.StudentDetails.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Student/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            StudentDetail studentDetail = db.StudentDetails.Find(id);
            if (studentDetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(studentDetail);
        }

        public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults()
        {

                return PartialView("_StudentLocation");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your UI is not really making sense. And why are you not just including the dropdown lists in the initial view (make them hidden if that is what you really want) And what are the dropdownlists for anyway? (and partial view do not include `<html>`, `<head>` elements etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment. I have to implement similar situation in my project. So I have created dummy project. The Index page displays the two Students Name. And each student Name has Search button. If I click on 1st search button then 1st drop down should display and similarly for 2nd one. Please guide me.

Comment: And what happens when there are 3 students. What would the 3rd button do? (sorry but this is just not making any sense, and you still have not explained what the dropdownlists are for)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, As I mentioned, this is just dummy project so I want to just get an idea how to call 1st drop down on 1st click and 2nd drop down on 2nd button click. So for that I have created only 2 Students Name and 2 drop down lists.  So that, it would be easy to understand. I hope you got some clear idea. Thank you.

Comment: For a start you need 2 separate partial views, one for each dropdownlist. And then you could include an identifier of some sort in your buttons (say a `data-id="@someValue"` attribute) which you get in the `.click()` handler and pass to the controller method to identify which partial to return back to the client. But its clear you have an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I understand that if I create 2 separate Partial views for each dropdownlist then it solves the problem. But I want to create a single partial view with different data. Is it possible to do that? As in real scenario, I have 20 dropdownlists and each with different data. So I do not think it is a good idea to create 20 partial view for that. If I can create a single partial view with 20 dropdownlists then display each dropdownlist based on button click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159966/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160028/discussion-between-raj-and-stephen-muecke).